# Subclassing tkinter.Menu results in default menus

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, menu

I'm trying to create a tkinter GUI application while organizing my code into classes for the main application, the frame, and the menu. For the menu, I'm subclassing tkinter.menu, but it's giving me a bunch of default menus and not including the menus and commands I've created.  I've stripped it down as best I can to the following working example that illustrates the problem:

First I subclassed tkinter.TK to create the main widget, containing the main window and the menu.  For illustration, I included one empty method to add as a command in the File menu. Next, I subclassed tkinter.Frame to create the main frame.  For illustration, I added a text box to the frame. Finally, I subclassed tkinter.Menu to create the main menu and added the submenu "File" and a command "Open".

```
import tkinter

class Application(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.main = MainWindow(master=self)
        self.menu = MainMenu(master=self)

        self.main.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)

    def open(self):
        pass

class MainWindow(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master = master
        self.textbox = tkinter.Text()
        self.textbox.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)

class MainMenu(tkinter.Menu):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tkinter.Menu.__init__(self, master=None)
        self.master = master
        self.file = tkinter.Menu(self)
        self.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.file)
        self.file.add_command(label="Open", command=master.open)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().mainloop()
```

The result is a bunch of menus I didn't create, including a File menu without my "Open" command:

[Here's a screen cap of the results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7oqW.png)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please don't section your code like that. If you have explanations in between use `# comments` _in_ the code.

Comment: I am _unable_ to produce any menus at all combining code pieces you've provided.

Comment: Fixed the formatting.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
self.menu = MainMenu(master=self)
```

with:

```
self['menu'] = MainMenu(master=self)
    # or self["menu"] = MainMenu(master=self)
    # or self.config(menu=MainMenu(master=self))
    # or self.configure(menu=MainMenu(master=self))
```

or add:

```
self['menu'] = self.menu
# or self["menu"] = self.menu
# or self.config(menu=self.menu)
# or self.configure(menu=self.menu)
```

anywhere after:

```
self.menu = ...
```

to have your menu assigned as *the* menu to your `Toplevel`-like widget.

Comment: @TheLatinist it does the same thing as `self.configure(menu=self.menu)`.