# Python Tkinter Menu bar is not shown

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have the following code that is not displaying the menu.  It worked until I moved the menu out into a class.  I added the `self.configure(menu=self.menu)` based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48600439/subclassing-tkinter-menu-results-in-default-menus) but it still doesn't work.  The print statements show me the menu building code is running.

Am I getting a reference to the parent correctly?

If I mistakenly reference the event handlers from the parent instead of the controller, the error indicates this is a Tk() object.

I am using python3.6 and tkinter8.6 on Ubuntu.

```
import tkinter as tk
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.main = MainWindow(self)
        self.menu=MainMenu(self, self.main)
        self.configure(menu=self.menu)
        self.minsize(300,300)
        self.geometry("500x500")
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.main.on_exit)
        self.main.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
    def on_exit(self):
        print("exiting...")
        self.parent.destroy()
    def on_choose_port(self):
        print("on_choose_port selected")

class MainMenu(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, master=None)
        self.master = parent
        self.controller = controller
        print("building menu bar")
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self.master)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.file_menu(self.menubar))
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=self.settings_menu(self.menubar))

    def file_menu(self, parent):
        print("building file menu...")
        file_menu = tk.Menu(parent)
        file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.controller.on_exit)
        return file_menu

    def settings_menu(self, parent):
        print("building settings menu...")
        settings_menu = tk.Menu(parent)
        settings_menu.add_command(label="Port", command=self.controller.on_choose_port)
        return settings_menu

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `MainMenu` inherits from `Menu`, but also creates an internal menu which has all of the other menu items. You attach `MainMenu` to the root window, but you've attached all of the cascade menus to the hidden `self.menubar` menu.

In other words, you need to be adding your cascade menus to `self` rather than to `self.menubar`, and you don't need to create `self.menubar` at all.

```
class MainMenu(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, master=None)
        self.master = parent
        self.controller = controller
        print("building menu bar")
        self.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.file_menu(self))
        self.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=self.settings_menu(self))
```

Comment: Thanks... (he says sheepishly)  Works perfectly.